# If Instance is for Class, what's for Template?

Tags: terminology, templates

I am not able to find the right technical term to mention child or instance of a template.
What's the right one, child or instance or something else I am not aware of?
Sorry for my unclear original question.
Its not related to any language. The Template I am talking about is a business concept in my application. 
Say for example, I have a "chair" template. I would set a few property values to it to create it's usable instances.
I need this for naming and documentation stuff.
Shortlisted 3 terms: Instance, Definition, Child. Whats suits better?

Comment: Is it possible to clarify your question a bit more please? For example, what language are you using? Could you give an example of a related template?

Comment: Is this in C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a [definition](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc16explicit_instantiation.htm)?

> You can explicitly tell the compiler when it should generate a
>   definition from a template. This is called explicit instantiation.

but I think an 'instantiation' is more usual terminology, so 'instance' is just as good for templates too.

Answer (score 5):

According to the book [C++ Templates - The Complete Guide](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/) (chapter "Termonology"), it is called "specialization". The process of creating a specialization is called instantiation.

Answer (score 3):

**Instantiation**. That's it..

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the instantiation of template is done like `vector<int> testVector;` in this case `testVector` is just like any other ordinary object.

**BONUS:**
In many other languages, (Not C++ to my knowledge) there is a concept called [metaclass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaclass) who's instances are classes.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what template means in this context but in one conceptual interpretation of the word an instance of a template could be considered a **`prototype`**, or perhaps **`archetype`**, **`blueprint`**, **`definition`**

Answer (score -4):

I'd use "view" to describe an instance of a template.

Comment: Maybe am example would help of how to use "view" would make this a better answer...

Comment: If the Op meant ASP.NET, this would be a good answer.